# How to select value by index in Reactive Form Angular 12?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have below code

```
<select formControlName="test">
   <option value="1">A</option>
   <option value="2">B</option>
   <option value="1">C</option>
   <option value="1">D</option>
</select>
```

I have same value. How to select by index. I want to default selected as C in typescript.

Comment: Hmm.... where is the reactive form?

Comment: Hi @AT82 I didn't put TS code

Comment: Oh... ok... well you didn't have anything regarding reactive form in your template either... but now I see that you edited your question and added formcontrolname.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select name="test">
   <option *ngFor="let opt of options; let index = index" [value]="opt.value" [selected]="index === 2">{{opt.label}}</option>
</select>
```

in your ts:

```
options = [
  {
    value: 1,
    label: 'A'
  },
  {
    value: 2,
    label: 'B'
  },
  {
    value: 1,
    label: 'C'
  },
  {
    value: 1,
    label: 'D'
  },
]
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hmggbg)

Comment: Hmm... does this actually work with a reactive form? By my experience `selected` is overridden by the formcontrol value....

Comment: it worked on stackblitz

Comment: You are not using a reactive form there

Comment: Reactive form: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ex51df?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of `selected`.

```
<select name="test">
   <option value="1">A</option>
   <option value="2">B</option>
   <option value="1" selected="selected">C</option>
   <option value="1">D</option>
</select>
```